# Facebook API Social plugins wont load on 3rd party website

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, web

I had a curious issue today where the Facebook API code that was dispensed from developers.facebook.com wouldn't work at all in modern browsers. (It worked in IE 8, and Opera 12).

I assumed it was Javascript related, and fiddled, tried other FB code (like Facepile etc) and it just. didn't. work.

What I was trying to embed was the Like Box, but I tried the simple like button too.

What irritated me the most about this was that all the help on the internet suggested that I "just change the sdk.js to all.js and your problems will magically go away" - which in this case, wasn't true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pulling in code I knew worked from other sites we've done, and finding them mysteriously stop working in place I added/removed/drilled down through the site structure and eventually found it.

There was a div with the ID of ***FB***. (a facebook link/logo in the header of the site.)

That was it. Renamed that one div, and everything started working again.

I hope this will save you the hours I've wasted on this.